# How to change a bluetooth dongle mac address in .NET?

Tags: .net, api, bluetooth, mac-address

I need to programmatically change a dongle mac address.
The reason is: I have several dongles communicating together and some have the same mac address.
I'm trying to do this in a .NET program. Any API to do this?
Thank you.